# How can i protect my Parse android SDK keys

Tags: android, web-services, security, parse-platform

i was playing on my Android app apk
and i try to decompile it then i found my keys is viable to any one who will try to decompile it 
if someone use my keys on another app he can get data from parse easy right ? 
He can make new app with the key and he can make query to find all users data
how can i protect my keys ?
Thanks

Comment: They would still need to know a correct user login. I would make sure to protect server side instead using ACL etc.. In my opinion the app keys are not supposed to be secret.

Comment: No i mean he Can make query from his new app to get all users info for example

Comment: You can restrict access in the data browser on Parse.com. For example making impossible to query a class if you are not logged in. And again, alternatively, each user could also be locked by removing the public read on the ACL.